# export ui from figma/adobe xd to python(tkinter and kivy)

Tags: python, tkinter, kivy

can I export ui element from ui software to kivy and  tkinter?

I did not try but I want to learn that before I dive into tkinter more and more.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I doubt you can do that.  I use kivy and I can recommend it.  There may be other options.  If you are just learning, I don't suggest using tkinter.  It is old and there are other more modern options.  You would be able to use image files such as .png in Kivy but this would  be a low level function.